# Specifying EPSG:31370 CRS in R Leaflet for WMS-service returns blank tiles

Tags: coordinate-system, proj4js, leaflet-r, proj4leaflet

I am trying to load historical map tiles from a WMS-server ([GetCapabilities](https://geoservices.informatievlaanderen.be/raadpleegdiensten/histcart/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&)) and display them using R Leaflet.

Using the default CRS in Leaflet works fine, using e.g.:

```
leaflet() %>% 
  setView(4.69839084, 50.880089, zoom = 14) %>%
  addWMSTiles(
    "https://geoservices.informatievlaanderen.be/raadpleegdiensten/histcart/wms",
    layers = list("ferraris"),
    options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png"),
    attribution = "Source: GIS Geoservices Informatie Vlaanderen")
```

However, the projection [should](http://www.geopunt.be/catalogus/datasetfolder/2d7382ea-d25c-4fe5-9196-b7ebf2dbe352) be [Belge 1972 / Belgian Lambert 72 (EPSG:31370)](https://epsg.io/31370).

I can specify an example CRS (EPSG:3006), and the tiles still load:

```
epsg3006 <- leafletCRS(crsClass = "L.Proj.CRS", code = "EPSG:3006",
  proj4def = "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs",
  resolutions = 2^(13:-1), # 8192 down to 0.5
  origin = c(0, 0)
)
leaflet(options = leafletOptions(crs = epsg3006)) %>%
...
```

However, using the epsg.io Proj4js-string for EPSG:31370 **results in gray/blank tiles** in R Leaflet:

```
epsg31370 <- leafletCRS(
  crsClass = "L.Proj.CRS", code = "ESRI:31370",
  proj4def = "+proj=lcc +lat_1=51.16666723333333 +lat_2=49.8333339 +lat_0=90 +lon_0=4.367486666666666 +x_0=150000.013 +y_0=5400088.438 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-106.869,52.2978,-103.724,0.3366,-0.457,1.8422,-1.2747 +units=m +no_defs",
  resolutions = 2^(13:-1), # 8192 down to 0.5
  origin = c(0, 0))

leaflet(options = leafletOptions(crs = epsg31370)) %>%
  setView(4.69839084, 50.880089, zoom = 14) %>% # center on Leuven
  addWMSTiles(
    baseUrl = "https://geoservices.informatievlaanderen.be/raadpleegdiensten/histcart/wms",
    layers = list("ferraris"), # request Ferraris-tiles from available WMS tilesets
    options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png"),
    attribution = "Source: GIS Geoservices Informatie Vlaanderen") %>%
  addControl("Leuven on the Ferraris map (1777)", position = "topright")
```

Additionally/possibly related:

- I'm not sure how the resolutions-arguments work. Should I be able to find that through WSM GetCapabilities?
- Proj4js returns a depreciation warning:

> Warning in leafletCRS(crsClass = "L.Proj.CRS", code = "ESRI:102003",
>   proj4def = "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0
>   +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs", : projectedBounds argument is
>   deprecated and has no effect, use the bounds argument.

Comment: Do you mean ESRI:31370 in your code, the service has EPSG:31370

Comment: You found any solution for `Proj4js` approach? I had to resort to `rgdal` library for conversion of the coordinates to `WGS84`, prior to drawing.